# How to find the derivatives of powers of $f$ using the definition of derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

have a homework problem that is just stumping me!

Basically I cannot use any derivative rules and I can only use the definition of derivative to solve these:

$$g(x)=f^2(x)$$

$$g(x)=f^3(x)$$

$$g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$$

$$g(x)=\sqrt[3]{f(x)}$$

I know how to use the definiton of derivative fairly well and I know what the answers should be, but I just can't get them to work out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: any standard book on analysis. See bartle and sherbert

Comment: You haven't communicated what you are objective is. "solve these" makes no sense. Through context I might guess you are asked to differentiate these functions $g$, with results in therms of $f$, but that's not clear. Is that the task?

Comment: You must first show what you have tried

Comment: Yes, I need to find g'(x) in terms of f'(x), f(x) and x

Answer (score 2):

For the first example, you secretly know the result $g'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$, which may help as a guidance for a direct approach:
You have $$\begin{align}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} &=\frac{f^2(x+h)-f^2(x)}{h}\\&=\frac{f^2(x+h)-f(x)f(x+h)+f(x)f(x+h)-f^2(x)}{h}\\&=(f(x+h)+f(x))\cdot \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\end{align}$$ 
and see what happens as $h\to 0$, noting especialy that $f(x+h)\to f(x)$ holds because $f'(x)$ exists.

The same trick works for the second problem.

For the third problem, you can sort-of recycle the first result, as we find
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =(g(x+h)+g(x))\cdot\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$$
from $f(x)=g^2(x)$. The reason for $g(x+h)\to g(x)$, however, is a different one (we cannot yet use the existence of $g'(x)$). Also be careful about the case $g(x)=0$.

Similarly, the fourth problem relates to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)?  Assuming you are asked for $g'(x)$ in each case, for the third we can define $h(y)=y^3$, then $g(x)=h(f(x))=h'(f(x))f'(x)=3(f(x))^2f'(x)$  The others are similar

Comment: quote "I cannot use any derivative rules and I can only use the definition of derivative"

Comment: I can't use any of the the rules. Not the chain rule, nor the product rule, nor the power rule. Using just algebra and the defintion of derivitive

Comment: OF course the chain rule itself follows from just algebra and the definition of derivative ...

Answer (score 0):

By Chain Rule, we know that the derivative of $[f(x)]^2$ should be $2f(x) \cdot f'(x)$. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} [f(x)]^2
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(x + h)]^2 - [f(x)]^2}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[f(x + h) + f(x)][f(x + h) - f(x)]}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \left[[f(x + h) + f(x)] \cdot \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\right] \\
&= \left[\lim_{h \to 0} [f(x + h) + f(x)]\right] \cdot \left[\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\right] \\
&= [f(x + 0) + f(x)] \cdot f'(x) \\
&= 2f(x) \cdot f'(x)
\end{align*}
as desired. Try something similar for the other problems.

Comment: with g(x) set = to f(x), would I just replace the all of the f's in the above function you just typed out for me with g's instead?